# How can i load the url image from CSV

Tags: html, csv

i am trying to load the url image from CSV on my html but i cant. I got the url in text and i want the image. I am using this code:

```
    <script src="d3.min.js?v=3.2.8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
        d3.text("productdata.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
    </script>
```

and the CSV got this: Id_text, Name_text, Description_text, Price_text, Image_text, Url_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would append an img tag to the dom and set the src attribute to the url from your csv